# Passing array of functions in passProps causes Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

#### Issue Description

When passing an array of functions in the `passProps` prop of `navigator.push` I get the following error:

```
Malformed call from JS: field sizes are different.
```

#### Steps to Reproduce / Code Snippets / Screenshots

```
navigator.push({ screen: 'anyScreen', passProps: { anyKey: [() => {}] } });
```

[image: android screenshot]

---

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: react-native-navigation@^1.1.352
- React Native version: react-native@^0.55.3
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): Android
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Nexus 6P / Android 8.1.0

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Can you please let us know if you have resolved this issue. because we are facing the same.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on this project since then. No update about this :/